# Retrieve data from Config. PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have file in folder assets/includes/config.php

The file contains this data:

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'xxxx';
$db_username = 'xxxx';
$db_password = 'xxxxx';
$site_url = 'https://xxxxx.xx/';
```

How can i echo this data in index.php so it would be visible for everybody ?
Thank you!

Comment: You want to `echo` it, as in, actually display it on the screen? Or just import the variables so that they can be used?

Comment: Yes to actually display it on the screen not to import.

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea and I can't think of any reason why you'd ever want to do this, but `echo file_get_contents(...)` would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `echo` before all code lines.
For example

```
echo $db_host = 'localhost';
echo $db_name = 'xxxx';
echo $db_username = 'xxxx';
echo $db_password = 'xxxxx';
echo $site_url = 'https://xxxxx.xx/';
```